# Why foreach output twice the result

Tags: php, foreach

i have an issue with my code, as said in the title, i got twice the result. have seen plenty of topics about this but i don't find my particular solution. thanks for helping!!

```
<?php
foreach($liste_vol as $index =>$vol)
{

    $etape = 1;
    $liste_route = get_routeData($vol->idVol);
    $nb = count($liste_route) - 1;
    echo '<tr>
              <td><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></td>
              <td>' . $liste_route[0]->dateDebut . '</td>
              <td>' . $liste_route[0]->OACIdep . '-' . $liste_route[$nb]->OACIarr . '</td>
              <td>' . $vol->dureeTrajet . '</td>
              <td> ' . $vol->immatAvion . '</td>
              <td>';
    foreach ($liste_route as $index2 => $route) {
        echo '<div> ' . $etape . ' ' . $route->OACIdep . '-' . $route->OACIarr . '</div>';
        $etape = $etape + 1;
    }
    echo '
         <td> ' . $vol->qualif . '</td>
         <td> ' . $vol->remarques . '</td></tr>';
}
?>
```

I'm using this as function to access my database:

```
    function get_volData($idUser)
{
    $dbh = connexion();
    $tab = array();

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM vol JOIN avions ON vol.idAvion = avions.idAvion
       JOIN vuedureetrajet ON vol.idVol = vuedureetrajet.idVol WHERE idUser=:idUser ORDER BY vuedureetrajet.heureDep";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->bindParam(":idUser", $idUser, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute() or die(print_r($sth->errorInfo(), true));

    while( $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $tab[] = $result;
    }
$sth->closeCursor();
return $tab;

}
```

the other function is quite similar and has the same fetch method

The var_dump($liste_vol) returns :

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (9) { ["idVol"]=> string(1) "1" ["idUser"]=> string(1) "1" ["idAvion"]=> string(1) "1" ["qualif"]=> string(22) "vol aux instruments IR" ["remarques"]=> string(28) "Contournement orage sur Agen" ["typeAvion"]=> string(11) "CESSNA C172" ["immatAvion"]=> string(6) "D-EGCD" ["idCompagnie"]=> string(1) "6" ["dureeTrajet"]=> string(8) "03:15:00" } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#4 (9) { ["idVol"]=> string(1) "1" ["idUser"]=> string(1) "1" ["idAvion"]=> string(1) "1" ["qualif"]=> string(22) "vol aux instruments IR" ["remarques"]=> string(28) "Contournement orage sur Agen" ["typeAvion"]=> string(11) "CESSNA C172" ["immatAvion"]=> string(6) "D-EGCD" ["idCompagnie"]=> string(1) "6" ["dureeTrajet"]=> string(8) "03:15:00" } 
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#5 (9) { ["idVol"]=> string(2) "14" ["idUser"]=> string(1) "1" ["idAvion"]=> string(1) "1" ["qualif"]=> string(4) "test" ["remarques"]=> string(4) "test" ["typeAvion"]=> string(11) "CESSNA C172" ["immatAvion"]=> string(6) "D-EGCD" ["idCompagnie"]=> string(1) "6" ["dureeTrajet"]=> NULL } 
    [3]=> object(stdClass)#6 (9) { ["idVol"]=> string(2) "14" ["idUser"]=> string(1) "1" ["idAvion"]=> string(1) "1" ["qualif"]=> string(4) "test" ["remarques"]=> string(4) "test" ["typeAvion"]=> string(11) "CESSNA C172" ["immatAvion"]=> string(6) "D-EGCD" ["idCompagnie"]=> string(1) "6" ["dureeTrajet"]=> NULL } }
```

Comment: This won't show the results twice by itself. You must be running it twice.

Comment: I have seen plenty of questions like this, and it's *always* the reason. Check your webserver access log.

Comment: @barmar that's not the issue according to my access log.

Comment: What does `var_dump($liste_vol)` show?

Comment: @barmar i've edited the post and objects appears twice

Comment: Then the problem is with whatever created `$liste_vol`, it's putting duplicates into the array.

Comment: If it's a database query, try using `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot